# Shell commands in Flutter

Tags: shell, flutter, dynamic

I am developing a desktop UI in Flutter and I need to create buttons to execute shell commands.

I already can execute some commands simple such as `ls -l` and it shows its results nicely in the console.

However I need a way to show the results in the main app and not in the console, I have tried the snackbar but it is not so nice and it does not get the outputs from other commands that gives dynamic outputs.

I would like to watch dynamic outputs such as `tail -f` and `top`.

How could I open a new window in the flutter app to show the execution of a command?

For now, I have this:

```java
class LsButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Process.run('ls', ['-l']).then((ProcessResult results) {
              Flushbar(
                title: "Output",
                message: results.stdout,
                duration:  Duration(seconds: 15),
              )..show(context);
            });
          },
          child: Text('Show dir contents!',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 10,
          ),)
      ),
    );
  }}
```

Comment: Hey `Process.run` which package is this

Comment: Hi! Sorry for super late response! Is from dart package, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter [doesn't yet support multiple windows](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30701), so currently if you want to do that you'd have to do it via native code, controlled via platform channels.